# which word is correct to use? And or or?

Tags: prepositions, word-usage

In the following sentence which is correct to use? And or or?

"I have the choice between Tony or Samantha"
"I have the choice between Tony and Samantha."

Answer (score -1):

"Between" must be used with "and." Hence,

*I have a choice between Tony and Samantha.*

is correct.

However, since we're referring to a choice here, "or" too makes sense. But, "and" is the best bet if you're confused about which one to choose since "and" would be correct grammatically.

Also, I think the article "a" is more suited here.

Hope I answered your question.

I recommend the following sites for great grammar info:

http://englishisducksoup.com

http://www.queens-english-society.com

Comment: Jason Bassford, you can use "or" with "between" when you talk about choices. It's not contradictory. It's an option to not restrict yourself to "and."